# SSIS Recordset Destination error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have an SSIS package targeted at SQL Server 2012.

I have it deployed into the `Stored Packages` in Integration Services and then have a SQL Server Agent job which executes it.

The first part of the package which moves data from a number of tables from a live database into a staging database execute successfully. I then have a data flow task which uses a Recordset Destination to collect a list of IDs of other records to move into the staging database.

When I execute the package manually by doing a `Run Package` from Integration Services (through SQL Server Management Studio) the package executes successfully, running the dataflow task which uses the recordset destination, however when run through the SQL Server Agent job I get the following error

> Message
>   Executed as user: xxxx. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.2100.60 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  09:51:49  Error: 2013-03-18 10:16:02.73     Code: 0xC000F427     Source: xxx_dataflowtask_xxx SSIS.Pipeline     Description: **To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Recordset Destination of Integration Services or higher.**  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  09:51:49  Finished: 10:16:02  Elapsed:  1452.78 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Do you have SQL Server Integration Services for SQL 2012 installed on the server?

Comment: yep! the other parts of the package work if this section is disabled

Comment: What edition of SQL Server is installed on the server?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 enterprise

Comment: Well so much for that idea.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475354/ssis-recordset-destination-error and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/9ca73adc-a9fc-4ce6-9064-658a726d0e00

Comment: If it's really this urgent, contact Microsoft Product Support.

Comment: Is cross-posting not allowed?

Comment: It's strongly discouraged within the Stack Exchange network. I posted the link to the MSDN forums as well because I found it through Google while I was searching.

Comment: Despite the error message stating the problem is with the Recordset Destination, it smells much more like a permission issue (works fine for manual execution, automated execution fails). What account is the SQL Agent running under? Is the Integration Services job step executed under a stored credential? Either way, does the account have access to the file system where your `BufferTempStorage` and/or `BLOBTempStoragePath` are located (defined per data flow)? By default, those will go to `%temp%` See http://www.bimonkey.com/2008/04/blobtempstoragepath-and-buffertempstoragepath/

Comment: I've tried setting that and still no luck

Comment: My SSIS package is deployed into the "File System" section rather than the MSDB part of Integration Services, should that make any difference?